# running .html as .php

Tags: linux, php, .htaccess, php5, mod-fcgid

How do I edit my .htaccess file using mod_fcgid to turn .html files to act as .php

I tried:

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .html
```

Did not work. I am using cpanel and using php 5.3 and apache 2.2.

Comment: What is the motifivation to do this?

Answer (score 1):

yes that directive is correct, but you have to add that directive to the .htaccess in any directory, or in alternative you can add it in your httpd.conf file. Ensure that the module is loaded with `a2enmod` command

Comment: yea, i added that to .htaccess. no luck.

Comment: are you sure the module is loaded correctly?check it from apache and from phpinfo

Comment: module? mod_fcgid is loaded in the apache file and all the other 100 sites run fine. Just need to have one vhost run .html as .php

Comment: I'd try with SetHandler instead AddHandler, anything from the logs?

Comment: I found a nice link that may help you ....   http://isp-control.net/forum/printthread.php?tid=5430